# Git: Don't push merged/pulled branches

Tags: git, branch

I am looking for a solution to a problem I seem to be running into more and more working on distributed projects that change quickly.  Here is the problem statement:

There are a number of developers working on improving a common code base in github that uses the `master` branch.  Each one spins up their own fork/branch and develops their features independently.  In this scenario these developers are making a significant change to `master` so the split up the work.   Each one takes a set of independent fixes that they resolve and push back.  Each would create their branch/fork in a typical manner:
`git checkout -b featuredev master`

Lets assume that developer 2 finishes his code and creates a pull request that everyone agrees is correct but it is delayed being merged into master due to lack of resources.   Developer 1 wants to get these fixes so he can use them.  So he pulls them into his current development branch using something like `git pull /ref/123/head` to get the code into his current repo.

Developer 1 finishes his work and now wants to push his fixes back to the server.  If he does a `git push` git will correctly push his source into the pull request and it will also include all of the commits from developer 2.  So now when developer 1 creates a PR it has all of his commits and all of developer 2's commits in it which are encompassed in another pull request.  Is there a way for developer 1 to push just his code changes and not the commits from developer 2?  Am I generating a scenario that doesn't matter?  Right now the only way I have found to isolate developer 1's changes is to go through an annoying rebase operation to remove developer 2's commits from the branch before doing a push.

Comment: The best solution here is to not let the scenario happen where you need to directly merge one feature branch into another one.  If that has to happen, then maybe you can just wrap up the source feature branch there and then, and let the target branch become the bearer of both sets of features.  Synching up frequently with your `master` branch is also a generally good thing to do.

Comment: I agree it is a very sub optimal path.  Unfortunately it seems to happen frequently on open source projects where the package maintainers are very slow in approving pull requests and contributors are very fast at implementing changes.

Comment: An example I ran into just the other day for myself.  Someone had implemented a change and added a PR that had been sitting un-merged for two weeks for broken functionality.  I was implementing a fix to another piece of broken functionality but needed the un-merged PR to get the code to compile.  So I could either 
1) re-implement the fix myself to get the code to compile.
2) pull the fix into my branch to fix compilation problems.

In either case I don't really want the other persons fixes in my PR just the fixes related the problem I was resolving.